# telnet web terminal

Tags: python, django

Любые идеи по созданию telnet веб терминала, аналог putty только через веб.
Веб framework django. Консоль на js реализована.

---

Советуют использовать fastapi или же tornado.

Необходимо создавать сессию и держать подключение с устройством.

класс telnet подключения:

```
class TelnetClient():
PROMPT = b'#'
LISTPROMPT = [b'#', b'--More--', b'<space>']
LISTAUTHLOGIN = [b'User Name:',b'login:']

def __init__(self, ):
    self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet()

def login_host(self, host_ip, username, password):
    try:
        self.tn.open(host_ip, port=23)
    except:
        return False #network failure
    self.tn.expect(self.LISTAUTHLOGIN,timeout=5)
    self.tn.write(username.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
    self.tn.read_until(b'Password:', timeout=5)
    self.tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
    if self.tn.read_until(self.PROMPT):
        return True #successful login
    else:
        return False #Login failed

def execute_some_command(self, command):
    self.tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    print('<br>'.join([(f"{k.decode('ascii')}") for k in self.tn.expect(self.LISTPROMPT)[2:]]))

def getsoket(self):
    return self.tn.get_socket()
# Exit telnet
def logout_host(self):
    self.tn.write(b"exit\n")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно изучение исходных кодов https://guacamole.apache.org/ подтолкнёт вас на решение

Comment: Суть вопроса в чём?